# BlockingQueue Works improperly with stringbuilder

Tags: java, stringbuffer, blockingqueue

I was trying to enqueue a set of strings with a thread (say thread1) into a BlockingQueue and write these queued items to a file with a different thread (thread2). A simple producer - consumer problem.

Thread1 :

```
while(condition) { queue.add(data); }
```

Thread2 :

```
while(true) { queue.take(data); //write the took data }
```

This whole operation works fine with the data being String.  When I try to do the same operation with a StringBuilder, the results are random.

if the enqueued data is "This is my data", the output is "y data" or "is my data" or some random subset of the entire data ( sometimes the expected entire data too )

Is it the Blocking queue's nature to behave this way to stringBuilders or am i doing it wrong??

Comment: String is immutable so it is thread safe, stringbuilder is not thread safe, stringbuffer is thread safe, Also dont forget to add proper synchronization in thread.

Comment: How about showing the code where you're actually using `StringBuilder`? Since `StringBuilder` is mutable, I can imagine that your bug is coming from reusing the same `StringBuilder` instance. In any case `BlockingQueue` is innocent here.

Comment: wow. Thanks @Kayaman. That was my issue. I was reusing the StringBuilder.  Is there any other way than creating a new StringBuilder for each data.

Comment: Why are you using `StringBuilder`? Does the receiver intend to append more data to it? If not, send it as a `String` and you can reuse it (if that matters to you so much).

Comment: @Kayaman I could use the String. But each data is unique and that would lead to creation of lot of strings.

Comment: You'll be creating a lot of objects anyway. Sounds like you should be using just `Strings`. You're not going to keep them in memory forever after all, are you?

Comment: no @kayaman. I don't want them in memory. But the producer will create each data by appending some characters. Won't using strings create a new string for each append operation.  With all these constraints, Is there a trade-off I could opt for?

Comment: Uh, use a `StringBuilder` to create the full data you want to send and then put `myStringBuilder.toString()` in the queue. Come on, this isn't rocket science.